# Is there an XML, containing all big cities, their TimeZone offset to the UTC?

Tags: xml, timezone, global

I'm searching for an XML, which contains all major cities in the world, their offset to the UTC, and also, start and end of daylight saving times.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: DST is much more complicated than that.

Comment: I think its not easy, but maybe someone knows an XML which is nearl to my needs...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at the [GeoNames.org](http://www.geonames.org/export/ws-overview.html) API, maybe this helps you out?

Answer (score 2):

It is not possible to create what you're asking for.  The UTC offset at a particular location depends on the current date and time, location, local laws, national laws and international laws.  The last three can change at any time.  This is why there's a whole timezone system, which must be updated regularly, to manage these calculation.  Start by reading this [Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_zone).

Comment: yeah, i know they can change, so i'm asking for one, covering this very moment.

Comment: If you only care about this very moment, why did you ask for "start and end of daylight saving times"?

Answer (score 1):

Not XML, but probably the closest thing you can get for what you need: [TZ database](http://cs.ucla.edu/~eggert/tz/tz-link.htm)